# Cakephp + RDS + SSL: certificate verify failed

Tags: ssl, cakephp, rds

I have a Cakephp3.8 website, connected to a RDS database. I am trying to use an SSL database connection.

I got the pem certificate from AWS. I have created a test user with access to my database, and this user is set up to require SSL.

I can successfully connect to the database with my user from the command line:
`mysql -u ssl-user -p -h xxxxx.xxxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com --ssl-ca=./rds-ca-2019-root.pem`

I have set up my database connection in CakePHP as follows:

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'xxxxx.xxxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'username' => 'sl-user',
        'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'database' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'ssl_ca' => '/var/www/rds-ca-2019-root.pem',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'log' => false,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => true,
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
    ],
],
```

With the above setup I the connection fails and I get the following error:

```
Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
Caused by: [PDOException] PDO::_construct(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_sertificate:certificate verify failed (/var/www/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php:92)
```

Any ideas why CakePHP can't connect?

Comment: You probably need to provide the `ssl_key` and `ssl_cert` files as well? I'm assuming that the command line is picking those up automatically from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Actually realised that the RDS server was running MariaDB 10.3.x. AWS provide specific docs for MariaDB: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MariaDB.html#MariaDB.Concepts.SSLSupport

The solution for me was to use the combined certificate:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem